# ElasticSearch Node Prompting For Authentication

Tags: elasticsearch

I followed the following instructions for installing [Elasticsearch 7.5.2 on windows](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/windows.html). The only modification I made to setup was selecting the basic license as opposed to the trial license. After installation, I issued a get request to my elasticsearch node on port 9200 and I receive the following response:

```
{
error: {
root_cause: [
{
type: "security_exception",
reason: "missing authentication credentials for REST request [/]",
header: {
WWW-Authenticate: "Basic realm="security" charset="UTF-8""
}
}
],
type: "security_exception",
reason: "missing authentication credentials for REST request [/]",
header: {
WWW-Authenticate: "Basic realm="security" charset="UTF-8""
}
},
status: 401
}
```

I've tried authenticating through browser based auth popup using credentials user:elastic with no password, as well as user:elastic password: changeme as suggested from other elastic forums with no success. I've also attempted the same method via postman, with basic authentication. Is there a way to simply turn off authentication for testing purposes?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to turn off authentication by editing the elasticsearch.yml file located in C:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\config

Setting `xpack.security.enabled: false` did the trick.

In my case, I also had to restart the elasticsearch windows service as well.